Nodejs ES6 import issue with AWS Lambda & Layer
I'm using NodeJs(ES6) on AWS Lambda with node_module as AWS Layer and I want to publish a message on SNS.
The above code works perfectly with CommonJs syntax but using import syntax (ES6) facing an issue with aws-sdk/sns-client as this is commonsJS module.
Package.json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-sns": "^3.370.0",
  },
  "type": "module",
}


My code same as mentioned in AWS Documentation.
Node Modules added into nodejs directory and zipped it as a layer.
../lib/snsClient.js created as mentioned in the documentation.
Tried with nodejs16.x, nodejs18.x and nodejs.20.x and mjs extension.
Want to use ES6 due to some dependencies.

ERROR
2024-05-05T20:50:31.064Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Named export 'AWS' not found. The requested module 'aws-sdk' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.\nCommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:\n\nimport pkg from 'aws-sdk';\nconst { AWS } = pkg;\n",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Named export 'AWS' not found. The requested module 'aws-sdk' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.",
        "CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:",
        "",
        "import pkg from 'aws-sdk';",
        "const { AWS } = pkg;",
        "",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1084:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}

Tried following as well,
import pkg from 'aws-sdk'; 
const { AWS } = pkg;

Thank you in advance.

var AWS = require("aws-sdk") is a AWS SDK v2 thing.  You currently are including the v3 version - you need to install v2 to get that to work.  Otherwise, to use v3 you need to use import { SNSClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-sns" I recommend staying with v3 since v2 is really old.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_sns_code_examples.html

You are currently including the v3 version of SNS:
"dependencies": {
  "@aws-sdk/client-sns": "^3.370.0",
},

But you are using as if it were a v2 package:
import pkg from 'aws-sdk'; 
const { AWS } = pkg;

So either you need to include the v2 version of aws-sdk (not a good idea)
or you need to use it like it is a v3 package:
import { SNSClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-sns";
...
const client = new SNSClient({});

You can see examples for v3 here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_sns_code_examples.html
Edit:
Here is some instructions for upgrading code to v3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/migrating.html
If you want AWS to do it you can do this:
npx aws-sdk-js-codemod -t v2-to-v3 .

